# Practicing functions in program to find volume of triangular prism. Tried debugging my code but can't figure out why it's not working

Tags: javascript, function

I am a newbie practicing writing functions with this program to find the volume of a triangular prism using 3 different functions. Despite all my debugging efforts, I can't figure out why it doesn't work. I tested my math and the math works. Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Volume of a Triangular Prism</title>
        <script>
            /* Function triangleArea() is called by prismVolume(), which is called by 
               doInputOutput(). 
             * doInputOutput() is the only function that takes use input and outputs result to a div.
            */

            function doInputOutput() {
                var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('aInput').value);
                var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bInput').value);
                var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cInput').value);
                var length = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lengthInput').value);

                var vol = prismVolume(a, b, c, length);

                // Rounds to 2 places.
                var digits = 2;
                var mult = Math.pow(10, digits);
                var volume = Math.round(tVol * mult) / mult;

                document.getElementById('volDiv').innerHTML = volume;
            }

            function prismVolume(a, b, c, length) {
                var s = (a + b + c) / 2;
                var area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));

                var tVol = area * length;
                return tVol;
            }

            function triangleArea(a, b, c) {
                var s = (a + b + c) / 2;
                var area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
                return area;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This program will compute the volume of a triangular prism.<br>
        Please enter the following triangular prism measurements:<br>
        Side 1: <input id="text" id="aInput"><br>
        Side 2: <input id="text" id="bInput"><br>
        Side 3: <input id="text" id="cInput"><br>
        Length: <input id="text" id="lengthInput"><br>
        <button type="button" onclick =doInputOutput()>Volume</button>
        <div id="volDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `input`s like so

```
Side 1: <input type="text" id="aInput"><br>
Side 2: <input type="text" id="bInput"><br>
Side 3: <input type="text" id="cInput"><br>
Length: <input type="text" id="lengthInput"><br>
```

Currently you're giving the `input` elements 2 ids, but what you want is to set the type to be text and then have that custom id.

Also, you need to move the `tVol` variable to the `prismVolume()`:

```js
/* Function triangleArea() is called by prismVolume(), which is called by 
          doInputOutput(). 
        * doInputOutput() is the only function that takes use input and outputs result to a div.
      */

function doInputOutput() {
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("aInput").value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById("bInput").value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById("cInput").value);
  var length = parseFloat(document.getElementById("lengthInput").value);

  var volume = prismVolume(a, b, c, length);

  document.getElementById("volDiv").innerHTML = volume;
}

function prismVolume(a, b, c, length) {
  var s = (a + b + c) / 2;
  var area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));

  var tVol = area * length;

  // Rounds to 2 places.
  var digits = 2;
  var mult = Math.pow(10, digits);
  var volume = Math.round(tVol * mult) / mult;
  
  return volume;
}

function triangleArea(a, b, c) {
  var s = (a + b + c) / 2;
  var area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
  return area;
}
```

```html
This program will compute the volume of a triangular prism.<br />
Please enter the following triangular prism measurements:<br />
Side 1: <input type="text" id="aInput" /><br />
Side 2: <input type="text" id="bInput" /><br />
Side 3: <input type="text" id="cInput" /><br />
Length: <input type="text" id="lengthInput" /><br />
<button type="button" onclick="doInputOutput()">Volume</button>
<div id="volDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues. But the biggest one is that `tVol` is undefined. This causes the function being run to crash so you get no result. You can see this in the browser by using the console in debugging tools.

First change your inputs:

```
  Side 1: <input type="text" id="aInput"><br>
  Side 2: <input type="text" id="bInput"><br>
  Side 3: <input type="text" id="cInput"><br>
  Length: <input type="text" id="lengthInput"><br>
```

Second:

`tVol` is the wrong variable. Change your function read:

```
function doInputOutput() {
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('aInput').value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bInput').value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cInput').value);
  var length = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lengthInput').value);

  var vol = prismVolume(a, b, c, length);

  // Rounds to 2 places.
  var digits = 2;
  var mult = Math.pow(10, digits);
  var volume = Math.round(vol * mult) / mult;

  document.getElementById('volDiv').innerHTML = volume;
}
```

you will notice that in `Math.round(vol * mult) / mult;` I changed `tVol` to `vol`

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your code I have fixed that code and please try to match with your existing code base and understand logic why we were facing that issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Volume of a Triangular Prism</title>
        <script>
            /* Function triangleArea() is called by prismVolume(), which is called by 
               doInputOutput(). 
             * doInputOutput() is the only function that takes use input and outputs result to a div.
            */

            function doInputOutput() {
                var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('aInput').value);
                var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bInput').value);
                var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById('cInput').value);
                var length = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lengthInput').value);

                var tVol = prismVolume(a, b, c, length);

                // Rounds to 2 places.
                var digits = 2;
                var mult = Math.pow(10, digits);
                var volume = Math.round(tVol * mult) / mult;

                document.getElementById('volDiv').innerHTML = volume;
            }

            function prismVolume(a, b, c, length) {
                var s = (a + b + c) / 2;
                var area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));

                var tVol = area * length;
                return tVol;
            }

            function triangleArea(a, b, c) {
                var s = (a + b + c) / 2;
                var area = Math.sqrt(s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c));
                return area;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        This program will compute the volume of a triangular prism.<br>
        Please enter the following triangular prism measurements:<br>
        Side 1: <input id="aInput"><br>
        Side 2: <input id="bInput"><br>
        Side 3: <input id="cInput"><br>
        Length: <input id="lengthInput"><br>
        <button type="button" onclick=doInputOutput()>Volume</button>
        <div id="volDiv"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now your program runs correctly.